# Understanding the meaning of basis

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

I am having a really hard time when I try to grasp vectors and its relation to the basis in which they re expressed. Let me explain.
In an exercise, I am given three vectors and I am told that the image of the first of them, which is the vector v1 (1,2,3), equals 2 times v1.
Then what I do is the product of a vector by a scalar and so I would get (2,4,6), However, the right answer provided is simply (2,0,0). This is the thing I can’t get. I know it is related to the fact that v1 is expressed in the standard basis but I have not been given a clear explanation on what is really going on with it.
Can someone shed some light on this in the  clearest way possible?

Comment: What do you mean, "the image of the first of them"?  If $\vec v_1$ is twice the first vector in the standard basis, then in that basis $\vec v_1=(2,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emphasize the point in the second paragraph of [gimusi’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2649166/265466), don’t think of $(1,2,3)$ as the vector $v_1$, but as its representation relative to the standard basis. If you’re used to visualizing vectors as little arrows, think of $v_1$ as the arrow itself. To describe this arrow, you need to pick a coordinate system. In the coordinate system that we consider “standard,” the head of this arrow has the coordinates $(1,2,3)$—from its tail you go a distance of $1$ in the $x$-direction, then a distance of $2$ in the $y$-direction, and then a distance of $3$ in the $z$-direction. That’s what those coordinates mean—they’re instructions for reaching the arrow’s head from its tail.

If you pick a different coordinate system, that is, a different basis, the arrow itself doesn’t change, but the instructions for reaching its head from its tail—its coordinates—do. Each vector in a basis defines a direction and a unit of length in that direction. If $v_1$ is the first element of a basis, then the first coordinate of a vector tells us how many multiple of $v_1$’s length to move in its direction as the first step in reaching the head of the vector.

It’s common to call the standard basis vectors $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$. Going by the meaning of coordinates relative to a basis explained in the previous paragraph, then, relative to the standard basis the coordinates of $2v_1$ are $(2,4,6)$, meaning that to get to the head of $2v_1$ you need to go twice the length of $e_1$ in that direction, then $4$ times the length of $e_2$ in its direction, and finally $6$ times the length of $e_3$ in that direction. Alternatively, you can just go twice the length of $v_1$ in the direction of $v_1$. That puts you at the head of $2v_1$, so there’s no need to move any more, thus, the coordinates of $2v_1$ in any basis in which $v_1$ is the first vector are $(2,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying answer! But if as you say, you can write (2,0,0) instead of (2,4,6), why is the latter incorrect? Should not it still be ok although it is much less simple?

Comment: @Timetraveler The latter are the coordinates of $v_1$ in the standard coordinate system—relative to the standard basis. The former are its coordinates in the *other* coordinate system, one in which $v_1$ is the first element. To put it in perhaps more familiar terms, would it be correct to say that the polar coordinates of the point with Cartesian coordinates $(1,0)$ are $(1,0)$ instead of $(1,\pi/2)$?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the basis which contains $\vec v_1$ as first vector, the vector $v_1$ is expressed by $(1,0,0)$ and $2\vec v_1$ is exactly expressed by $(2,0,0)$.

The key point is to distinguish between vectors, which are invariable entities, and their representation with respect to a given basis which is expressed in term of components.

Notably, once we have fixed a basis $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3$ we say that $\vec w=(a,b,c)$ if

$$\vec w=a\vec v_1+b\vec v_2+c\vec v_3$$

since we identify $\vec w$ with its components $(a,b,c)$ with respect to the given basis.

Comment: But is not v1 expressed by (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) as well? Are not you then  treating the first component of v1 as if it were the vector v1 ?

Comment: @Timetraveler to define a basis you need an order set of linearly independent vectors, if $v_1$ is the first its representation is$ (1,0,0)$

Comment: So basically, when you have a basis, from the first vector you only “care” about its first component”, from the second one, the second component and so on? Sorry for being so annoying making questions

Comment: @Timetraveler what do you mean with "care about"? as already pointed out the fact is that when we have a basis $\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3$ we can express any vector  $\vec w=a\vec v_1+b\vec v_2+c\vec v_3$ thus in that basis we identify $\vec w$ with its components $(a,b,c)$ with respect to the given basis.