# Matrices of linear transformation, help with what this basis means.

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

I don't understand this, doesn't $\mathbb{R}^n$, have the standard vectors as basis? How can $x$ then have the basis $B$ if it's in $\mathbb{R}$.
The book just says that $B$ is some arbitrary base.

Comment: If $v$ is of dimension $n$ then  $T(v)$ has at least $m-n$ null components when $m\gt n$ and otherwise when $m\lt n$.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse elements of the vector space $V$ with their coordinates relative to some ordered basis, which are elements of $\mathbb R^n$. This can be especially confusing when $V=\mathbb R^n$. You might find the discussion in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3473026/265466) helpful. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2649595/265466) is shorter, but covers some of the same ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Any $n$-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. An easy and very useful isomorphism is the coordinate isomorphism with respect to some basis $B$:

Consider a vector $v= \sum_{i=1}^n v_i b_i$ where $\{b_i\}=B$ and $v_i\in\mathbb{R}$. The coordinate isomorphism with respect to $B$ is then the map $v\mapsto (v_1,...,v_n)^t$. So you just map a vector to the column vector containing its coefficients with respect to $B$ and I assume that this column vector is what they mean by $[x]_B$.